# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition returning wrong results

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

When I use the geolocation service in the usual manner like for example :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition1,errLocation, {maximumAge:0, timeout:40000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
            }
function showPosition1(position) {console.log(position.coords)}
```

I get a result which is extremely off. When I check using position.coord.accuracy, it shows to be 260 km! That is very far from where I am.

Any idea why this is the case even though highAccuracy is enabled and the browser permits location and everything?

I am using my mobile data's hotspot to connect to internet on my laptop. Can this be a big issue?

Answer (score 4):

GeoLocation features use MANY different ways to figure out your location.  In addition to the standard ways, Chrome at least one additional.

- GPS co-ordinates --  If available, these are the most accurate.
- Geo-IP -- Try to look up the IP address and find its location.  This is known to be wildly inaccurate
- (Chrome) Access Point Names -- The Google Maps van also collects Access Point (SSID) and their location.  Chrome will use your current access point to try to find your location.

If your access point moved, it can throw off things.  If you have to resort to Geo-IP, accuracy is a crap-shoot.

In addition, using proxy servers or VPNs will make Geo-IP useless.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! I understand how it can be very off. But since I am connecting to my mobile hotspot, and in my mobile itself when I check, it gives very accurate result. But my laptop which is using that hotspot is giving wrong result. 
Since my laptop doesnt have gps it probably uses other services which is resulting in poor results. But how is it that the IP or Access point names be different than that attached to the mobile? 
Also is there a way out to truly find a correct location in this case? Or is it always by chance?

Comment: Since I don't know how your setup is works, I can't answer specific questions.   I'm not sure if the browser APIs can even tell you which method they used.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wanted to show a user's position on the map, so now I decided to give the user the freedom to move his marker in case the geolocation API gives wrong results. I simply wasn't aware that this can be an option. So now a user can change his marker's position in case geolocation doesnt work well.